# Excel formula to extract string between 2 specific character

Tags: excel, extract

I have a data table that looks like this:

[image]

And am using the following forumula:
`=MID(LEFT(F2,FIND("D",F2)-1),FIND(" ",F2)+1,LEN(F2))`

With the goal of extracting the numeric value after the "D" character in my Visit column. Some visits have 1 digit after the "D", some are 2, max will be 3 digits. However, the formula I've tried to use above is returning blanks and #VALUE! only. I figured the number character between the D and the space would work, but then I realize not all will have the space (see C2D16). Can someone explain what I am doing incorrectly?

TIA

Comment: You are getting `#VALUE!` Error because there is space before each `PREDOSE` where as for the one which dont have the same, shall give you an error, because your formula searches for a space which it is not able to locate!

Comment: That makes sense- so the ones that do have a space, why is it returning a blank?

Comment: Yeah absolutely, check the answer, and try that one, it should work fine, without any further hassle!

Comment: Thanks @MayukhBhattacharya - that formula below did work. I've never had to use =MAX() before, and am not terribly familiar with =SUBSTITUTE() either, AND I'm unsure of why the /1 is in there- I'll do some research to try and figure out each component of that formula. Thanks again

Comment: I shall share the whole explanation, below give me a moment !

Comment: Right on, idk if this site has some sort of reputation system but I would love to rep you if I could!

Comment: I have just edited the answer, please refer madam,!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

Here is an explanation of how the below formula works,

```
=MAX(IFERROR(MID(SUBSTITUTE($F2,"PREDOSE",""),ROW($1:$10),3)/1,""))
```

First we are removing or substituting the word `PREDOSE` from the string, even if we don't have the word the function shall ignore and leave it as it is

```
=SUBSTITUTE($F2," PREDOSE","")
```

Next we are wrapping the formula with an `MID` function and for the start number we are using `ROW` function which breaks the string into 10 segments

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE($F2," PREDOSE",""),ROW($1:$10),3)
```

On selecting the formula & press **F9** or if you goto Formulas tab and **evaluate** you shall see it gives us an array

```
{"C2D";"2D1";"D1";"1";"";"";"";"";"";""}
```

Therefore we need to ignore the text part from the array, so we can either **multiply by 1**, **divide by 1**, **add 0** or we can use `double minus(--)` which **negates** the text values as **#VALUE!** error while leaves the **numeric part**

So, to exclude the error values we just wrap it within an **IFERROR Function**

```
=IFERROR(--MID(SUBSTITUTE($F2," PREDOSE",""),ROW($1:$10),3),"")
```

Which again on selecting and pressing **F9** shall give us an array of **number and blanks**

```
{"";"";"";1;"";"";"";"";"";""}
```

**Last but not least**, we need the numeric as an output, hence **MAX** comes to save us

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(SUBSTITUTE($F2," PREDOSE",""),ROW($1:$10),3),""))
```

and gives an output as we desire!

[image: EXTRACT_NUMBER]

Comment: One more way to resolve the query --> `=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F2,"D"," ")," ",REPT(" ",100)),100,100))*1`

Comment: You are a godsend my friend!

Comment: I have more alternatives madam, but the above two can easily make thing work out! Also note if you want `MAX` works well when you are trying to extract any length of  number from the string, in that scenario just change the `ROW($1:$10)` to a large number or you can use use `(ROW(INDIRECT("1"&LEN(F2)))` this shall do the work, !

Answer (score 2):

Your original approach would work as well, as long you handle the error. In order to investigate errors, like #value it's always a good idea to break down the formula into pieces to locate the issue.

=MID(F2,FIND("D",F2)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",F2)-FIND("D",F2)-1,LEN(F2)-FIND("D",F2)))

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another:

`=-LOOKUP(0,-(MID(F2,FIND("D",F2)+1,{1;2;3})&"**0"))`

Comment: Nice One Sir, I knew this one, but didn't know that about using `Double *`, sir how that works, I mean, we generally use `*` as a wild card, but when i evaluated your formula, it created an array, sir, if you please throw some light, just wanted to learn from you!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Try my formula without this concatenation, i.e. `=-LOOKUP(0,-MID(F2,FIND("D",F3)+1,{1;2;3;4;5}))` with `F2` containing "C2D1 PREDOSE" and see what you get. Not that it appears a possible entry here, but "C2D1 MARDOSE" would be another problematic example if we didn't apply this concatenation, at least for those with an English-language version of Excel.

Comment: Sir, it gave decimals for those containing "C2D1 PREDOSE" and the one without as whole number, while the last cell gave `#N/A` but i want to know what is the use of `**` is it working like a roundup function

Comment: Sir, understood now, really amazing trick thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula that I think is a little cleaner

```
=MID(F1,FIND("D",F1)+1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",F1),LEN(F1)+1)-(FIND("D",F1)+1))
```

I think this actually represents the thought process of what you are trying to do.

Breaking it down:

```
=MID(F1,X,Y)
```

You want the middle part of F1, starting at X with a Length of Y

```
X=FIND("D",F1)+1
```

Starting point (X) is one space after the first D

```
Y=IFERROR(FIND(" ",F1),LEN(F1)+1)-(FIND("D",F1)+1)
```

Length (Y) is X subtracted from either the position of the space character or 1 more than the length of the entire string